# How to retrieve the titles of a folder's children in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

It appears that listing the children of a folder doesn't actually return the titles of said children according to the [Google Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children#resource).

Do I have to query using the id of every single child to determine the name of the file/folder?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just occurred to me, is the way around this to do a search where the parent id is equal to the folder id I want to see the contents of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, listing the children of a folder only gives you their ids, so you have to send other queries to retrieve titles and the other metadata. I agree this is not optimal and we are considering making some changes here to improve the developer experience.

In the meanwhile, I'd recommend adopting your workaround and search for those files whose parent is the folder you want to see the contents of.

Comment: I think it makes sense that the search on the files resource return files, and the children returns references.

Comment: What about some example of such a query?

Comment: No doubt. What query IS needed to get folder names? I need to list folders in a particular parent, parse the names, then rename/move (creating alphabetical containers since Drive doesn't scale well). Having a VERY hard time seeing how to do such a simple task.

Comment: I don't understand why it would make sense to not return the titles and other metadata along with the children's list. Is there a use case where someone would request the children's list and not immediately query for the other information? It seems that at least the title should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You should use query params for `files.list()` method for getting that results,

In my example in **Python** it was:

```
service.files().list(maxResults=1000, q="'{0}' in parents".format(root_id)).execute()
```

all query params you could see [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters):

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking at how to get the title of a folders children assuming you already have the children(fileId) id's

```
function getFileProps(fileId, callback) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        'fileId': fileId
    });

    request.execute(function (resp) {
           callback(resp);
    });
}
```